# C++ How to use random device only once in one function when using it in combination with multiple uses of Mersenne twister in another function?

Tags: c++

Sorry for the long as not concise title, I don't really know how to work it better.

So I am trying to use std::random_device in combination with the Mersenne twister engine in an attempt to generate random trials. This has to be done millions of times and I have heard that it is best to only use random device once as it takes longer to generate a number from random device compared to seeding the Mersenne twister engine and using that each trial.

So that means trial function (which runs a lot) should not have random device into and only the mersenne twister engine and the random device should be in a different function that is only called once.

But I when I create the random device in the main function I can't use it to seed the mersenne twister in the trial function and if I seed it in the main function I can't seem to call it in the trial function in order to generate random number. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

This is what I have:

```
void trial() { 
    std::random_device rd;              // I want to create the random device only once
    std::mt19937_64 mt(rd());           // I don't know where/when/how to seed it so that I can put this part in the main function and still use this to generate random numbers in this trial function.
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(x, y);
    int number = dist(mt);
    // Other stuff

}
int main() {
     while(true) {
          trial();
     }    
  
}
```

Comment: Just pass in a reference to mt: https://onlinegdb.com/S1P1VbPXu

Comment: `static std::mt19937_64 mt(std::random_device()());` ?

Comment: Initializing this each time seems like a waste. Why not make a class you can instantiate once and then use multiple times? Like `X x` and then `x.trial()` as necessary.

Comment: For reference: https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/simple-portable-cpp-seed-entropy.html